# Need help to get correct values from checkboxes & dropdown select, to display correct data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm having trouble to get the correct data to display from Mat-Select and Mat-Checkbox.
What I want to do is get the values from the users that have been chosen. From the chosen values do a if-else statement to check if conditions are met, if met display the correct data view.  Also looking to dynamically change to the correct data view when the user updated their choices. 
I have the sample app running on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/tatemcg/angular-mat-sample 
Thank you for any help.

Html.

```
<div>
    <form>
        <mat-form-field id="dropdown1">
            <mat-label><h4>Continent</h4></mat-label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedSource" name="food" (selectionChange)="changeSources($event.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let source of dataSources" [value]="source.id">
                    {{source.sourceName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field id="dropdown2">
            <mat-label><h4>Country</h4></mat-label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedType" name="foods" (selectionChange)="changeCountryType($event.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let countryType of countryTypes" [value]="countryType.id">
                    {{countryType.countryType}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
        <mat-drawer class="insideDiv" #sideNav mode="side" opened="true" [position]="nav_position">
            Population Year
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li>
                    <mat-checkbox id="year2000" [(ngModel)]="twoThousandChecked" (change)="onYearCheckboxChange($event, '2000')"> 2000 </mat-checkbox>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="twoThousand10Checked" (change)="onYearCheckboxChange($event, '2010')"> 2010</mat-checkbox>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Gender
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li>
                    <mat-checkbox id="femaleCheckBox" [(ngModel)]="femaleChecked" (change)="onGenderCheckboxChange($event, 'female')"> Female </mat-checkbox>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="maleChecked" (change)="onGenderCheckboxChange($event, 'male')"> Male</mat-checkbox>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </mat-drawer>
        <mat-drawer-content>
            <button class="expandCollapseBTN" (click)="sideNav.toggle()" mat-button> Expand/Collapse </button>
            <div #dataViewNode id="dataNode">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h3>Here is your data for {{selectedType}} and {{yearNum}} and {{genderChoice}}</h3>
            </div>
        </mat-drawer-content>
    </mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

TS

```
export class DataViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {



  public selectedSource: string;
  public selectedType: string;


  dataSources = [
    { id: 'id1', sourceName: 'North America' }
  ];
  countryTypes = [
    { id: 'id1', countryType: 'Canada' },
    { id: 'id2', countryType: 'Mexico' },
    { id: 'id3', countryType: 'United States' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  changeSources(data) {
    alert("Continent " + data);
    console.log("Continent " + this.selectedSource);
    this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum);
  }
  changeCountryType(data) {
    alert("Country Selected" + data);
    console.log("Country Selected " + this.selectedType);
    this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum);
  }

  public yearNum = []; twoThousandChecked; twoThousand7Checked;
  public genderChoice = []; femaleChecked; maleChecked;

  onYearCheckboxChange(event, value) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.yearNum.push(value);
      this.yearNum = [...this.yearNum];
      alert("Year " + this.yearNum);
    }
    if (!event.checked) {
      let index = this.yearNum.indexOf(value);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.yearNum.splice(index, 1);
        this.yearNum = [...this.yearNum];
      }
    }
    this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum);
    console.log("Year List " + this.yearNum);
  }
  onGenderCheckboxChange(event, value) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.genderChoice.push(value);
      this.genderChoice = [...this.genderChoice];
      alert("Gender " + this.genderChoice);
    }
    if (!event.checked) {
      let index = this.genderChoice.indexOf(value);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.genderChoice.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum);
    console.log("Gender List: " + this.genderChoice);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum);
  }
  showSelectedDataView(selectedSource: string, selectedType: string, yearNum: any) {
    if (this.selectedSource === 'id1' && this.selectedType === 'id1') {
      alert("You Selected Data For " + this.selectedSource + " " + this.selectedType)
      console.log(" North America and Canada");
    }
    else if (this.selectedSource === 'id1' && this.selectedType === 'id2') {
      alert("You Selected Data For " + this.selectedSource + " " + this.selectedType)
      console.log(" North America and Mexico");
    }
    else if (this.selectedSource === 'id1' && this.selectedType === 'id3') {
      alert("You Selected Data For " + this.selectedSource + " " + this.selectedType)
      console.log(" North America and United States");
    }
    else if (this.selectedSource === 'id1' && this.selectedType === 'id1') {
      for(var i = 0; i < yearNum.length(); i++)
      {
        if(yearNum[i] === '2000')
        {
          alert("You Selected Data For " + this.selectedSource + " " + this.selectedType + " and Year " + this.yearNum)
          console.log(" North America and Canada and 2000 ");
        }
      }

    }
    else if (this.selectedSource === 'id1' && this.selectedType === 'id1' && this.yearNum === this.twoThousandChecked && this.genderChoice === this.maleChecked) {
      alert("You Selected Data For " + this.selectedSource + " " + this.selectedType + " and Year " + this.yearNum + " and for " + this.genderChoice)
      console.log(" North America and Canada and 2000 and Male");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code lies in with below code

ngOnChanges() {
    this.showSelectedDataView();
}

This is never triggered when user select any of the checkboxes. And the reason behind that is

> ngOnChanges only runs when the Input change comes from a template
>   binding like . If you set it manually
>   like this component.someInput = aValue, that happens outside the
>   change detection cycle and you need to let Angular know somehow that
>   you’ve changed something.

As the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) quote

> A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a
>   directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the
>   changes.

So in order to solve the  problem what you can do is.

**1. Either trigger change detection manually using below**

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

and then use

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

When you want angular to detect changes.

**2. Call you function `showSelectedDataView` when needed**
whenever you see there is a change and that should update the dataview call the required function in you code.

Also when you are working with arrays and objects if you use `.push` or change the value of a key that will not trigger the change detection. In that case you can use below to trigger the change detection.

```
this.yearNum = [...this.yearNum];
```

If object

```
const obj = {val: '123'}
obj.val = '345';
obj = {...obj}
```

Have update the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mjztj6) try it out.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Manish, thanks for the response.  I did some update, and call the showSelectedDataView() with its parameter in the drop down list change function.  It works as expected.  But for the checkboxes, I really don't know how to get that working or call the showSelectedDataView() with the correct parameters passed in the checkbox change function. Also edited my stackblitz.

Comment: OK so for that you will have to reassign the array to itself whenever you add or remove an item from it like this `this.yearNum = [...this.yearNum];` and call this function `this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType);` on the change event handlers of the checkboxes as i have mentioned in my answer as well. Here is an edited version of your stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mjztj6 Earlier changes were not reflected as thats a private stackblitz

Comment: I would also have to add in another parameter to the showSelectedDataView() right? would this work; showSelectedDataView(selectedSource: string, selectedType: string, yearNum : [] )?   Also I think I need to have a loop inside of the else if statement to process the array, to determine what is in the array and response to it right?  thanks!

Comment: That totally depends how you want utilize the data and the selections. So yes you might have to do that for your case.

Comment: I just want to get my last 2 else if statements to run and get the expected console.log().   So I have the.  showSelectedDataView(selectedSource: string, selectedType: string, yearNum : any ) and then call it else where like in the ngOnChanges() or   onYearCheckboxChange() with this.showSelectedDataView(this.selectedSource, this.selectedType, this.yearNum) . I'm still not getting the expected result in the else if statement with the for loop, that is inside of the showSelectedDataView(). I updated the above code and stackblitz. Not sure how to approach this, thanks for the any pointers.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly Please have a look. Now it will work according to your expectation and you you can add conditions to further handle scenarios.. Hope this solves your problem stackblitz.com/edit/github-mjztj6

Comment: I believe this will work.  Thank you.  But I think I see a potential problem in efficiency.  With the total number of combinations and possibilities, there would have to be A LOT of if else statements to catch all the combinations.  Do you know if there is a more efficient way to do this?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes there might be but will depend on your scenarios and the complexity of it.. but can only say once i see such cases to handle.. or there is even a chance that you may not have any option but using if and else constructs.